# Why do we we even exist?

Tags: earth, universe, big-bang-theory, fundamental-astronomy, space

It came to my mind one day that why does this universe even exist and why do we even exist and like we are enclosed in the so called atmosphere and a floating rock in space called the Earth, so is there any possibility that the universe is also enclosed in something and if it is, then what is outside that enclosure?

Comment: Turtles all the way down?

Comment: I doubt we can ever answer *why*, but for your last question, you might like to look up the [cosmic light horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_horizon)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about philosophy, but really too broad even for philosophy.SE

Comment: You might have better luck on philosophy.SE, but you're assuming there IS a reason, a logical fallacy.

Comment: _Nobody exists on purpose, nobody belongs anywhere, everybody's going to die. Come watch TV._

Comment: "Small, nasty and complicated."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's an interesting question, but as the comments say might be a better place to ask this question in the Philosophy SE site, but the question about the universe being englobed maybe by another much bigger 'space' is something we might never be able to prove right or wrong. This 'existential' question might refer to the holograph theory, the multiverse theory. The thing is, at the moment the only possible explanation of whats beyond the 'observable universe' boundary is nothing, neon, an infinite multi-dimensional plane of nothingness.